# Bug? Jupyter suddenly python2 even though it shows to use python3

Tags: python, pip, jupyter, jupyter-lab

Recently, I updated to pip to version 10 and installed 'Jupyter Lab'.
Now i just became aware that Jupyter is always launching a python 2 kernel even tough i explicitly tell it to use a python3 kernal

[image]
Has somebody else encountered this?

EDIT:

As it seems pip3 isn't properly working anymore:

```
$ pip3
bash: pip3: command not found
```

Even though:

```
$ apt install python3-pip
python3-pip is already the newest version (9.0.1-2).
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
```

EDIT2:

Because '$ python3' works properly, i checked the jupyer kernals:

```
$ jupyter kernelspec list
Available kernels:
  python2    /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/python2
  python3    /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3

Mabye this is helpfull regarding Tylers comment.
```

Comment: Can you please show us the output of echo $PATH in the terminal?

Comment: sure: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried several things, but what seemed to fix it was uninstalling and installing the kernel again.

```
$ sudo jupyter kernelspec remove python3  
$ sudo jupyter kernelspec install-self
```

If somebody has an idea what went wrong i would be happy to hear about it!
Thank you Tyler for the help!

Comment: I think it could be an issue with how you installed Python. you may run into issues again in the future related to this, but I'm glad for now it works for you!